# How to insert 2 answers using Quiz submodule Short Answer?

Tags: 7, quiz

I am using the [Quiz](https://www.drupal.org/project/quiz) module and enabled its submodule [Short Answer](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/quiz/tree/question_types/short_answer).

How can I insert two answers instead of one?

**Note**: Multiple choice is fine, but my problem is at Short Answer: I'm only able to add 1 correct answer, but my Quiz question has 2 correct answers.

Comment: If you are talking of marking an answer as correct, that is how I expect it should work, like Stack Exchange works. If you are talking of writing two answers, then that is different.

Comment: @kiamlaluno, my current situation is one short answer question has one or more answers.

Answer (score 0):

I guess no solution, so I just hack the module.

/public_html/testserver/the-exaple.com/sites/all/modules/contrib/quiz/question_types/short_answer

```
public function evaluateAnswer($user_answer) {
  ...
  switch ($this->node->correct_answer_evaluation) {
  case self::ANSWER_MATCH:
    if ($user_answer == $this->node->correct_answer) {
      $score = $this->node->max_score;
    }
    break;
  case self::ANSWER_INSENSITIVE_MATCH:

   ////////////////edit your code here

    break;
  case self::ANSWER_REGEX:
    if (preg_match($this->node->correct_answer, $user_answer) > 0) {
      $score = $this->node->max_score;
    }
    break;
}
...
}
```

Since I chose my answer is insensitive, I will edit second case.